# JSP - Getting object from DOM element

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm building an app using servlets and JSP (no framework). I have a List object, say an ArrayList of Book objects and using a < c:forEach > tag, I display the Book objects of the ArrayList in html (I'm using a Bootstrap card container for this.)

Now, when the user clicks on the card (for a CRUD operation), I need to get that particular book object for CRUD operations. Unfortunately, I'm not at all sure how to do this. May be store the object fields as parameters, somewhere?

This is my first servlet/JSP app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the book list, you should provide the way how you can access particular entity, for example like this:

```
<c:forEach items={books} var="book">
    <a href="host/book?id=${book.id}" >${book.title}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

This is the most common case when you don't use any framework. Be aware that in this case you will also need a servlet mapped for GET request /book.

Of course you can make an html form with action and hidden input with book id, however it's overkill.

Comment: Many thanks. I was thinking of using the second option and adding parameters, which I could later retrieve with JS, But I'll probably go with your suggestion.